# What is a JavaScript object.event = object.event = function()?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript so please go easy on me.

```
el.onmousemove = el.onscroll = function() {}
```

I can't seem to find what this piece of JS is doing. Can someone tell me what it's doing? I think it's an assignment and not a comparison because of the one equal sign, but I'm confused as to what it's assigning.

Is it basically creating/executing a function that is tied to when those events happen? If that's the case, doesn't that seem like a comparison?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's aliasing it, what its basically doing is assigning the same function to both `el.onmousemove` and `el.onscroll`

Comment: `onmousemove` and `onscroll` are the events which when triggered, respective given handler function `function()` will get executed..

Comment: To be precise, in this version with the brackets at the end it would assign the _return value_ of the function as the handler function (so the function would need to return a function reference). If you want to assign the reference to that function itself, then the brackets need to be removed.

Comment: @CBroe I suspect function is *literally* `function` (e.g., an anonyous function) which would mean it wouldn't get executed unless it's an IIFE.

Comment: _“If that's the case, doesn't that seem like a comparison?”_ – no, it doesn’t, because `=` is not the comparison operator, `==` is. And the result of an assignment in JS is the assigned value, so `foo = bar = 5` assigns the value `5` to both `bar` and `foo` in one go (because that statement is evaluated from right to left).

Comment: @DaveNewton: Well, then it would still need a function body to have any meaning, `foo = function() { … }`

Comment: I imagine he's removed the internals of what that function does for brevities sake?

Comment: I apologize, I've added curly braces to the function as it's defined there.

Comment: @CBroe Obviously; I think he was asking what the statement itself did, rather than including details about the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is aliasing the function. This means it is assigning the same function to both `el.onmousemove` and `el.onscroll`.

E.g. in JavaScript you can do something like `var a = b = '1.2'`. When you log `a` to the console it will be `'1.2'`, when you log `b` to the console it will be `'1.2'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's short for<sup>[1]</sup>

```
el.onscroll = function() { … };
el.onmousemove = el.onscroll;
```

and assigns one function to two properties. Yes, those event handlers will be called when the events occur; the function is not immediately executed - it's just created and passed around.

<sub>1: Not exactly, as the actual expression retains the value and does not use `el.onscroll` as a getter</sub>